# Passing a function f to the contructor of a class templated on the type of f

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, variadic

I'm exploring *two* different ways to pass a function to the ctor of a class template `Bar`, as shown below and [online](http://rextester.com/CVIDR81322).

Compliers tested: GCC 5.4.0 and clang 3.8.0. (The offending constructs are disabled in the online version.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cxxabi.h>

#define DEMANGLE( object )                                                          \
{                                                                                   \
    int status;                                                                     \
    char* name = abi::__cxa_demangle( typeid( object ).name() , 0 , 0 , &status );  \
    if( !status ) std::cout << name << std::endl;                                   \
    delete name;                                                                    \
} 

template<typename T> 
struct Bar;

template<typename ...Args> 
struct Bar<void(Args...)>
{
#if 0
    Bar( void(Args...) )        // OKAY 
    {                           // Question 1: need to assign a name to the function void(Args...)
    }
#else
    Bar( void(Args...) func )   // ERROR
    {
    }
#endif    
};

void wiggle( bool , short , int )
{   
}

template<typename F>
void wrapper( F f )
{
    //DEMANGLE( f )             // optional print out of the type of F
    Bar<F> bar( f ) ;           // Question 2: incomplete type error -- why is specialization of Bar not chosen???
}

int main()
{
    wrapper( wiggle );
    Bar<decltype(wiggle)> f( &wiggle );
}
```

**Question 1**

My first attempt to pass the function `wiggle` to `Bar` is to directly instantiate the latter as follows `Bar<decltype(wiggle)> f( &wiggle )`. The problem is how to name/reference the function passed to the constructor `Bar::Bar(f)`. Writing the ctor with an unnamed argument `Bar( void(Args...) )` compiles okay, but when I attempt to name or reference the argument passed to the ctor, like so `Bar( void(Args...) func )`, I get a compiler error

```
source_file.cpp:23:21: error: expected ')'
        Bar( void(Args...) func )       // ERROR
                           ^
source_file.cpp:23:5: note: to match this '('
        Bar( void(Args...) func )       // ERROR
```

**Question 2**

My second attempt to pass the function to `Bar` uses the function `void wrapper( F f )` in order to invoke `Bar<F> bar( f )`. Oddly both compilers reach for the (unimplemented) base template of `Bar` instead of the specialization, which generates the error

```
source_file.cpp:37:9: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Bar<void (*)(bool, short, int)>'
        Bar<F> bar( f );
               ^
source_file.cpp:42:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'wrapper<void (*)(bool, short, int)>' requested here
        wrapper( wiggle );
        ^
source_file.cpp:13:8: note: template is declared here
struct Bar;
```

What's specially confounding is that type name info dump macro `DEMANGLE` confirms that the type of `F` passed to `wrapper` is `void (*)(bool, short, int)`.

Comment: What do you want to do with `func` inside the constructor? After?

Comment: Remove the DEMANGLE stuff from your question. It just clutters things. Also, Holt's answer is correct.

Comment: @Holt I'd rather not go into all that. It will add more information than is necessary. Lets just say I'd like to call `func`. Thanks for your answer BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `wiggle`  is implicitly converted to a function pointer when passed to `wrapper`, so the actual type of `F` is:

```
void (*)(bool, short, int)
```

...which cannot match `void(Args)`. You could use [`std::remove_pointer_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer):

```
Bar<std::remove_pointer_t<F>> bar( f );
```

---

Regarding your first error, `Bar(void (Args...) func)` is not a correct construct, `Bar(void func(Args...))` would be here, but [that would be equivalent to](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function):

```
Bar(void (*func)(Args...))
```

...which is much clearer (in my opinion).